# What does it mean to multiply a random variable by a negative constant?

Tags: probability, random-variables

I'm asked to find the distribution of $|X - Y|$. I know I have to calculate a convolution - I don't have a problem with that -, but what I don't understand is this $(-Y)$. In particular, $Y$ has discrete uniform distribution over $\{1, 2, ..., k\}$, therefore $P(Y = y) = 1/k$ for all $y$.

My immediate thought about $-Y$ was to multiply its $pmf$ by $-1$. However, about 2 seconds later I realized that I would be breaking the axioms of probability by having negative probabilities. So it wouldn't be a valid $pmf$. So my question is, **what does it mean** to multiply a random variable by a negative constant? And in this particular case, what is $-Y$?

For completeness, the problem is this:

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent random variables with discrete uniform distribution over $\{1, 2, ..., k\}$. Determine the probability function of $Z = |X - Y|$.

Comment: $-Y$ has a uniform distribution over {-1,...,-k}.

Answer (score 3):

A random variable is just a function from the sample space of an experiment, $\Omega$, to the real numbers, $\mathbb{R}$. Multiplying a random variable by $(-1)$ is the same as multiplying any function mapping into the reals by $(-1)$. For example, let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x) = x^2$. Then the function $-f$, or $(-1) \cdot f$, is the function $-f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $-f(x) = -x^2$.

If you have a random variable $X: \{$apples, oranges, car $\} \to \{-2, 0, 5 \}$ and

$$X(\text{apples}) = -2$$

$$X(\text{oranges}) = 0$$

$$X(\text{car}) = 5$$

Then $-X: \{$apples, oranges, car $\} \to \{2, 0, -5 \}$, and

$$-X(\text{apples}) = 2$$

$$-X(\text{oranges}) = 0$$

$$-X(\text{car}) = -5$$